# Why is my web app failing to reload on open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

I have a simple web app that I want to update by using JavaScript. It actually loads data from a website but in this demo you will see it fails writing "Hello World". While it may not be "best practice" code it reproduces my issues I have with more complex code.

If I open this in Safari on iOS 11 the page shows "Hello World". I can refresh and do whatever I want. But if I add the page to the home screen (app icon) AND clean Safari caches, the following will happen:

I open the web app and everything works. But if I close it, go to Mail and back to the web app it only shows a white screen - until I clear caches from Safari...

Additionally, if I close and open the web app repeatedly it will eventually crash.

Any ideas what the issue could be?

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.getScript("test.js", function(){update();});</script>
    </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
function update() {
    document.write("<html>");
    document.write("<head>");
    document.write('<title>test</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">');
    document.write("</head>");
    document.write("<body>");
    document.write("Hello World");
    document.write("</body>");
    document.write("</html>");
}
```

Comment: Does it write some error to dev console?

Comment: What I get in the system log is an "assertion failed: ... libxpc.dylib". But nothing else that I could track down to the code.

But at least I have the same behavior on the iPhone Simulator.

Comment: why do you need jQuery there? All you actually do is write to document via plain old vanilla JS...

Comment: It is because I wanted to reproduce an issue with web apps in general. The code isn’t really useful, but this should work though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**test.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>
      </title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script>
   update();
</script>
```

**test.js**:

```
function update() {
    $(document).prop('title', 'test');  // or document.title = 'test';
    $('head')append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">');
    $('head')append('<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">');
    $('body').html('Hello World');
}
```

Comment: The thing is I want to find out why my web app fails. So even if my code isn't the best it still should work.  Btw. .append() works as well BUT the app fails as well.

Comment: It looks like the app does work. However because I have this issue with some other code as well I need to find out why this happens. For example if I add lots of append() to body it fails as well.

Comment: In your page, there is already <html> <head> and <body>. Your script you are trying to add them again. I think that the error is related to it.

Comment: I agree, but why does it work on Safari but not as a web app? This bug appears even when using .append() (30 times on a website). That's why I think it is not related. But it could be the caching itself that gets issues. If only I could just reload the web app every time it opens I could work around this...

Comment: if reload page without cache use:  location.reload(true);

Comment: Actually I want to use the cache but it should kind of "restart" the html and all its scripts.